# Rotate/ orientate a picture in fpdf python

Tags: python, fpdf

I want to add some pictures to my pdf I created with fpdf, but my problem is that I have have pictures in landscape and portrait orientation and I want them to have the same orientation in the document. Is it possible to rotate them? I only found a method to rotate the whole document.

I only have a basic code for now, but my question is, if it is possible for the orientation to be conserved?

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()

#pdf.rotate(-90)
for image in imagelist:
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(image,0, 0, w = 100)


pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

Comment: There's a library which can do that. You can rotate images using pillow. Docs: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate

Comment: See [this](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Transformations.html).